# Promise function not fetching resolve function

Tags: javascript, function, promise, settimeout

Below is the programme which I wrote having promise and settimeout concept.

```
var i = 1;
var x;
var z = 1
setTimeout(show, 8000);
setTimeout(show, 4000);
show();

function show() {
    console.log("Hello,show was called:- ", z);                    //to check if control is going inside show() function
    z++;

    x = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (i >= 1)
                resolve();
            else
                reject();

        }, 1000);
    });



}

x
    .then(
        () => {
            console.log("Resolve was called:- ", i);
            i++;

        }
    )
    .catch(
        () => {
            console.log("Wrong limit");
        }
    )
```

The Output being shown in is

```
Hello,show was called:-  1
Resolve was called:-  1
Hello,show was called:-  2
Hello,show was called:-  3
```

Why is that in first case , resolve function inside `.then` is being executed but for other 2 times , the control is not going to resolve function. I have even given enough time gap for it to process it. Why is it so that it is not executing resolve function ?

Comment: You're creating a new Promise each time `show` is called. You only attach the `.then()` to the first promise that you created with the first call to `show()` (line 6). The `show` executions created by the `setTimeout`s create new promises, but you never reattach a `.then()` handler to them, so you never see "Resolve was called" for them.

Comment: @NickParsons, I am actually new to javascript so maybe my query is bit weird.                                            But like everytime new promise is created but it has same name i.e `x`. So shouldn't it like go to `.then` and `.catch` declared with that variable only. Everytime new`x` is created but afterall it is same name, it should lead to same `.then`  . Like how will javascript know that this `.then` has been used  and even if it does is there some rule like one set of resolve reject can be used only once ?

Answer (score 0):

You are redefining x to a new Promise every time you run show but you are only   attaching a `.then()` to the first promise and therefore you only get one Resolve call.

If you move the `.then()` and `.catch()` inside the show then you attach it for every new promise you create.

When doing this you don't have to declare the variable outside, just create it as a constant variable inside the show function scope and this will be more clear too.

Here is a working code example:

```
// use let for developer experience
// let is a variable which can be updated and redefined.
let i = 1;
let z = 1;
setTimeout(show, 8000);
setTimeout(show, 4000);
show();

function show() {
  console.log("Hello,show was called:- ", z); //to check if control is going inside show() function
  z++;

  // use const for developer experience
  // const is a variable which can not be updated or redefined in the same scope. 
  const x = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      if (i >= 1) resolve();
      else reject();
    }, 1000);
  });

  x.then(() => {
    console.log("Resolve was called:- ", i);
    i++;
  }).catch(() => {
    console.log("Wrong limit");
  });
}
```

Comment: I am actually new to javascript so maybe my query is bit weird.                                            But like everytime new promise is created but it has same name i.e `x`. So shouldn't it like go to `.then` and `.catch` declared with that variable only. Everytime new`x` is created but afterall it is same name, it should lead to same `.then`  . Like how will javascript know that this `.then` has been used  and even if it does is there some rule like one set of resolve reject can be used only once ?

Comment: Not really no. When you are creating a `new Promise` you are creating a Promise Object. This promise object already have a .then() function from the start, this does nothing except passing the value on to the next function in the chain.

when you then are doing `.then(() => {function in here})`. You are redefining what the .then should do in that Promise Object.

Then the next time you create a X it is a completly new object, which then have the .then() function from the constructor of that Promise Object and therefore it does not have your .then function. Hope it helps! :)